# Bash: how to split a line by a delimiter and print each element on a new line?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a CSV file with a header that contains 2000+ columns. I wish to read only the first line then split it, and print each column name in a new line so I can grep to see if a columns exists. I am stuck

```sh
head -n 1 file.csv | ### what do do here? ### | grep var_i_want
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, it should be fast enough with `awk`(since you have mentioned a .csv Input_file so I have taken field separator as `,` if you don't have comma as a field separator then you may remove `FS=","` part from following code too).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\n"} FNR==1{$1=$1;print;exit}' Input_file
```

Since you haven't posted examples, so considering following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4,5,
```

Now after running code will get following output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\n"} FNR==1{$1=$1;print;exit}' Input_file
a
b
c
d
```

Since I am using condition `FNR==1` so it will read only very first Line, then I am using `exit` which will exit from program itself after completing operations on Line1 and will not read whole Input_file.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{            ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=","          ##Setting FS as comma here.
  OFS="\n"        ##Setting OFS as a new line here.
}
FNR==1{           ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  $1=$1           ##Re-arranging first field to make OFS into picture, since by default OFS is space and I am setting it as a new line.
  print           ##Printing current line here.
  exit            ##exit will make program exit.
}
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the line `$1=$1`? I can imagine it changing the separator between first field and the rest, but what about the other fields?

Comment: @User10482, sure, doing `$1=$1` will apply new value of OFS to current line. Its like re-assigning 1st field to itself to simply apply OFS to it(detailed explanation is attached in answer too), cheers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `tr`, like:

```
head -n 1 file.csv | tr "," "\n"
```

This will not handle fields with comma in them. If you have access to `python`, you can do:

```
head -n 1 file.csv | python -c 'import csv,sys; print("\n".join(csv.reader(sys.stdin).next()))'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` based approach:

```
$ sed -n '1s/,/\n/gp' file.csv
a
b
c
d
```

Explanation:

- `-n`: Print nothing by default.
- `1s/...` On first line, replace
- `s/,/\n/g`: replace all commas by newlines
- `.../gp`: print if the replacement is successful.

If there is a possibilty that the header line contains only one column, use

```
 $ sed -rn '1s/($|,)/\n/gp' file.csv
a
b
c
d
<an empty line is printed here>
```

Answer (score 0):

To print each column name in a different line:

```
IFS=,; for col in $(head -n1 file.csv); do echo $col; done
```

To search for a column name in the header:

```
head -n 1 file.csv | grep -o col_name
```